# Using Qt to make audio loopback capture

Tags: android, c++, ios, qt

Is it possible to use Qt to capture user output sound ?
I've trying to use my default output device (= my sound card) as input device, but it does not work :

```
QAudioDeviceInfo inputDevices = QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioOutput).at(0);

m_audioInput = new QAudioInput(inputDevices, formatAudio, this);

m_device = new MyIODevice(this);
m_device->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

m_audioInput->start(m_device);
```

If it's not possible with Qt, are here any multiplatform library to do that ? maybe OpenAL ? My target are Windows, Android, MacOS, iOS.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qtmultimedia-audiorecorder-example.html

Comment: This example record audio from microphone. I want to capture user system sound, as it goes out on the speakers. QAudioRecorder offers only interface for input devices.

Comment: Did you figure out a way to do this?